# How can I prevent the Visual Studio editor from breaking Javascript function declarations on dots?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2013

Sometimes when I add a function to the Script portion of my .cshtml file (in my ASP.NET MVC project), the Editor will switch into micromanagement mode and reformat all my Javacript/jQuery code and then put the cursor at the top of the file.

That's irritating enough, but adding insult to injury, it breaks all my functions on the "point"; that is, it changes code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

...to this:

```
$(document)
   .ready(function() {
```

That may be considered the preferred way (I don't know, and don't care much) but I don't want it. How can I prevent this from occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio was not the culprit, but Resharper:

[image]

I unticked/deselected the two "Auto-format" checkboxes.